# Windows 8 and Ubuntu using SSD as cache

Tags: installation, dual-boot, ssd

I'm new to the forum, and quite inexperienced working on Ubuntu, so be patient! haha.

I recently bought a new Laptop and I'd like to install ubuntu, while keeping some of the features it already has. The laptop is a Dell Inspiron 15R SE, with 32GB SSD + 1TB HDD, intel i7, 8GB, etc. The thing is that it has Windows 8 and the SSD is used as cache. Those are the two features I'd like to keep.

So, here's the question: Can I install Ubuntu so that both OS use the SSD as cache? Is that advisable? what steps should I follow or what things should I take special care about?

Thank you very much, and if you need more info, just ask

Juan.-

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot have a SSD for caching for both Windows and Linux.

Windows and Linux have caching program; ISRT from Intel for Windows, and [bcache](http://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/) for Linux. But these softwares are incompatible; they rely on the fact that after a reboot the partition is at the same way as it was when you shutdown. And dual booting destroys this expectation.

Perhaps, the SSD can be divided in two partitions, with each program using one partition. That, I think (but not sure), can be possible.